# Short hand If statement without else

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to have a short hand for an if statement as I am building an expression query and if test is null the accessor causes an error.

```
test != null ? test.Contains("mystring") : NO_VLAUE
```

I am looking for:

```
test != null ? test.Contains("mystring")

otherwise ignore.
```

I know I can use a `??` for `is null` but is there an inverse.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want `test != null && test.Contains("mystring")`

Your question as asked doesn't make sense.  All expressions, including the conditional operator, must have a value.  What would you expect that expression to evaluate to if `test` is null?

You probably want it to be false if test is null.
In other words, you want it to be true if test isn't null and it contains `mystring`.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you *might* want:

```
test != null && test.Contains("mystring")
```

That will evaluate to `false` if `test` is null - is that what you want? Basically you need to say what you want to happen if `test` *is* null, as otherwise it can't be used as an expression.